# Ninject.MVC3 + FluentValidation + Factory Has anyone used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, factory-pattern, fluentvalidation

I am in doubt about how to use the factory in [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) and [FluentValidatior](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation).

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315028/ninject-mvc3-nuget-webactivator-oh-my) helped me a lot, but I do not understand how to use the **factory to instantiate my validators**:

I also found some other articles [like this](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/02/22/using-fluentvalidation-with-an-ioc-container/) but with StructureMap!

## Follow the steps I performed

1. Installed [Ninject](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Ninject.MVC3) and [FluentValidation](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/FluentValidation.MVC3) via nuget
2. Installed [Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Ninject.Web.Mvc.FluentValidation) for factory class
3. And now?

When installing the Ninject, he created the `NinjectMVC3.cs`  in `App_Start` folder so I set my dependencies in `RegisterServices` method:

```
kernel.Bind<IHumanValidator>().To<ReCaptchaValidate>().InRequestScope();
```

In **Global.asax** the `Application_Start` method:

```
var ninjectValidatorFactory = new NinjectValidatorFactory(new StandardKernel());
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(ninjectValidatorFactory));
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
```

FluentValidator I have:

```
public class RegisterCoupleValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterCoupleModel>
{
    public RegisterCoupleValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(p => p.HumanValidator).SetValidator(new HumanValidator());
    }
}
```

**HumanValidator.cs**

```
public class HumanValidator : PropertyValidator
{
    [Inject]
    public IHumanValidator HumanValidate { get; set; }

    public HumanValidator(IHumanValidator hValidator)
        : this()
    {
        HumanValidate = hValidator;
    }

    public HumanValidator()
        : base("Texto digitado está incorreto. Por favor, tente novamente.")
    { }

    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
        return HumanValidate.IsValid();
    }
}
```

### My questions

1. In `RegisterCoupleValidator` class with the factory how do I not have instances the validators?
   Specifically in `new HumanValidator()`
2. In `HumanValidator` class the `HumanValidate` property always is null, why?

---

**Obs1:** I do not want to instantiate these validators of FluentValidator, I want Ninject to resolve the dependencies for me using this factory.

**Obs2:** I would not have to access the Ninject kernel, since in several posts I read that this would be an anti-partner.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this blog post](http://www.webpirates.nl/robin-van-der-knaap/20-setting-up-fluentvalidation-for-aspnet-mvc-using-ninject). The guy is using a NuGet package to setup FluentValidation with Ninject. It is pretty simple and well explained.